# I'm trying to get this javascript timer to start onclick but it will not start

Tags: javascript, timer, onclick, addeventlistener

Here is my javascript code.

```
var minutesLabel = document.getElementById("min");
var secondsLabel = document.getElementById("sec");
var totalSeconds = 300;
setInterval(startBlueTimer, 1000);
```

This is the part I am not really sure about. Im trying to only have this function be done when the button is clicked. I could be calling the onclick function wrong. Im not sure.

```
function startBlueTimer()
    {
        --totalSeconds;
        secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds%60);
        minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds/60));
    }

function pad(val) {
    var valString = val + "";
    if (valString.length < 2) {
        return "0" + valString;
    } else {
        return valString;
    }
}
   var stblue = document.getElementById("yosb");
   stblue.addEventListener("click", startBlueTimer, false);
```

Comment: onclick should be onClick

Comment: I don't see where a function called `setTime` is defined.

Comment: @Zak: wrong, it's all lowercase.

Comment: @MattBall im assuming user would have undefined error if setTime was not existing but user has hasn't mentioned it.

Comment: @MattBall I fixed my setInterval to setInterval(startBlueTimer, 1000) and named the function accordingly. I also added the event listener like Dave suggested. However, now the timer is starting as soon as the page loads and when clicked it just resets.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your click event, you should ideally use  `addEventListener`:

```
document.getElementById('yosb').addEventListener('click', function () {
    --totalSeconds;
    secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds % 60);
    minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds / 60));
}, false);
```

Further reading here: [AddEventListener Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)